# How good is the AI in the iOS port of Haggis?

Tags: computer-ai, haggis

I recently picked up the [iOS port](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/haggis/id465018604?mt=8) for [Haggis](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/37628/haggis). Although I own the physical version, and you can play it online at [boardgamearena](http://en.boardgamearena.com/#!gamepanel?game=haggis), playing versus the iOS AI has been my first experience with the game.

I generally beat the AI pretty handily at this point but I'm wondering if this is one of those games where the AI employs a strategy that can be successful against novices but cannot compete with even moderately experienced players.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My perspective is having never played Haggis until i played it on the ipad.  I have quite a bit of Tichu experience.
The AI offered competition to me for about 5 games.  After that i can beat it 4/5 of the time.

So overall i think it is a good way to learn the game, but will not help you get ahead online